# Unreachable MongoDB replica set using MAMP

Tags: php, mongodb, amazon-web-services, mamp

I'm running three remote instances replica set on AWS EC2 and opened the security group (firewall) on port 27017 and ICMP for my IP.

My developing environment is MAMP with PHP 5.6.2 on Mac OS X.
When new MongoClient in PHP test file, I provide a connection string:

> mongodb://52.68.25.131:27017,52.68.29.231:27017,52.68.50.99:27017/?replicaSet=rs0

Error shows:

> MongoConnectionException: No candidate servers found Caused by
>   MongoConnectionException: MongoClient::__construct():
>   php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname
>   provided, or not known

still unable to connect to the replica set. The following is the status of my replica set.

---

> rs0:PRIMARY> rs.status()

```
{
    "set": "rs0",
    "date": ISODate("2015-04-09T12:24:15.195Z"),
    "myState": 1,
    "members": [
    {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": "ip-172-30-0-126:27017",
        "health": 1,
        "state": 1,
        "stateStr": "PRIMARY",
        "uptime": 4714,
        "optime": Timestamp(1428578838,
        1),
        "optimeDate": ISODate("2015-04-09T11:27:18Z"),
        "electionTime": Timestamp(1428578787,
        1),
        "electionDate": ISODate("2015-04-09T11:26:27Z"),
        "configVersion": 3,
        "self": true
    },
    {
        "_id": 1,
        "name": "172.30.2.133:27017",
        "health": 1,
        "state": 2,
        "stateStr": "SECONDARY",
        "uptime": 3467,
        "optime": Timestamp(1428578838,
        1),
        "optimeDate": ISODate("2015-04-09T11:27:18Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2015-04-09T12:24:14.067Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2015-04-09T12:24:14.821Z"),
        "pingMs": 2,
        "syncingTo": "ip-172-30-0-126:27017",
        "configVersion": 3
    },
    {
        "_id": 2,
        "name": "172.30.2.132:27017",
        "health": 1,
        "state": 2,
        "stateStr": "SECONDARY",
        "uptime": 3414,
        "optime": Timestamp(1428578838,
        1),
        "optimeDate": ISODate("2015-04-09T11:27:18Z"),
        "lastHeartbeat": ISODate("2015-04-09T12:24:13.821Z"),
        "lastHeartbeatRecv": ISODate("2015-04-09T12:24:13.818Z"),
        "pingMs": 2,
        "syncingTo": "172.30.2.133:27017",
        "configVersion": 3
    }
    ],
    "ok": 1
```

Comment: Have a look at the names. This denotes the public interface MongoDB listens to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After assigning EIPs (Elastic IPs) to all three instances to get three public DNS and use them as the new config for replica set.

After `rs.reconfig(<new-setting>)` from primary node, it works like a charm.